# How use getElementById in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i transform this two ReactJS functions into React Native equivalents:

```
function mostrar(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
 }

 function fechar(id) {
   if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
 } else {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
 }
```

Its a function to show/hide components in a List

Comment: The real question is why you're using direct DOM manipulation to set styles in React in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of an onClick function for the list component.

I'm assuming you are using a map function to create your list.

```
<List> 
  {
     data.map(() => {
       <Component onClick={display => (display == true ? false : true)} /> 
     }
  }
</List>
```